# Activitymanager Start proc for activity after killing process

Tags: android

On close button I finish all activities and then kill process, but after this I can see in log:

Activitymanager  Start proc for activity (and one of the my finished activity is being started)

How can I avoid restarting process?

```
ActivityManager(1220): Process com.app.test (pid 3569) has died.

for several activities:
WindowManager(1220): WIN DEATH: Window{408d5498 com.app.test/Activity1 pa
used=true}

ActivityManager(1220): Start proc com.app.test for activity com.app.test/Activity1:
```

Comment: may be this will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121300/activity-restarts-on-force-close

Answer (score -3):

try `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` for kill your process on close button

Comment: I use it. Problem is in the other area.