# Using different contexts on startActivity makes App restart itself

Tags: android, android-activity, singleton, android-context

My app starts with a splashActivity.
In my Application, I start all my Singleton classes, one of them is ActivityController (Simplified code):

```
public class ActivityController {

    private static ActivityController INSTANCE = null;
    private final String TAG = "ACTIVITY MANAGER";
    static Context context;

    private ActivityController() {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);           
    }

    private synchronized static void createInstance(Context c) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            context = c.getApplicationContext();
            INSTANCE = new ActivityController();
        }
    }

    public static ActivityController getInstance(Context c) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) createInstance(c);
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

And this is my Application class:

```
public class Global extends MultiDexApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ActivityController.getInstance(this);       
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
        //etc...

    }
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

If I run this code, it starts MainActivity, but when I close the app (sliding finger), it restarts after few seconds. Always. It's impossible to close it.

The only way I've found to not have this problem is to start the `ActivityController.getInstance(this)` in the `OnCreate` of the SplashActivity, which is the launcher Activity. This way I can close the app and it won't restart.

Why is this happening? I think it's related with "context".

I've read this without any hint: [Activity restarts on Force Close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121300/activity-restarts-on-force-close)

Comment: Is onCreate of your Application being called? Throw some breakpoints or logs in to figure out what is getting called when.

Comment: @zgc7009 Yes, it's being called, each time it's restarted

Comment: Are you sure it isn't getting called which is causing your activity to launch when you call getInstance()?

Comment: @zgc7009 I don't understand you at all, it's called 1 time, when app is launched

Comment: Let's start from the beginning, why are you doing this? What is your "ActivityController" for?

Comment: @zgc7009 ActivityController will start X activity depending on some parameters that I've omitted to simplify code, I have this controller to avoid putting that code in SplashActivity, which is meant to be part of View, and should not contain this kind of code, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117234/discussion-between-zgc7009-and-borja).

Comment: We are working on moving this off of a static context reference